# Spark structured stream with multiple kafka clusters

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to get some basic info on spark structured streaming and reading from multiple topics on different clusters. I was able to find tutorials that shows how to pull from multiple kafka topics on the SAME cluster, but what if the topics are on DIFFERENT clusters? How does one read topics from multiple kafka clusters into spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sparkSession.readStream.format(....)` will return a `DataStreamReader`.  You can do this multiple times to create an `Array[DataStreamReader]`.  With those `DataStreamReader`, you can union them to return a single `DataFrame` which you can use however you wish.

```
  def getCombinedDF(streams: Array[DataStreamReader], topicName: String): DataFrame = {
    streams.map(rs => {
      rs
        .option("subscribe", topicName)
        .load()
    })
    .reduce(_.union(_))
  }
```

Our Kafka instance is load balanced across multiple clusters and this allows me to subscribe to the same topic on each cluster but process it as one.

Comment: You could subscribe each DataStreamReader to a different topic.  In my example above, I'm just mapping them all to the same one but you don't have to in theory.